# Replace characters in string multi-dictionaries

Tags: python, regex, string, dictionary

I have these single-line dictionaries which is read from standard input.

```
  def gen_with appropriate_name():
     for n, line in enumerate(sys.stdin): 
     d = ast.literal_eval(line) 
     items = d.values()[0].items()
     items.sort(key = lambda itm: itm[0]) 
     yield {n+1: {i+1:item[1] for i, item in enumerate(items)}}

  d = gen_with appropriate_name() # prime the generator 

  d.next() 
  for thing in d: 
     print thing
```

If you print 'd' then I get the o/p as the dictionary as I showed below.

```
 { 1 : {'1': 5, '2': 6, '3': 0} }
 { 2 : {'1': 6, '2': 4, '3': 0} }
 { 3 : {'1': 2, '2': 9, '3': 1} }
```

I want to convert them to this:

```
  1 1: 5 2: 6 3: 0
  2 1: 6 2: 4 3: 0
  3 1: 2 2: 9 3: 1
```

Since dictionary does not have a replace or re.sub method. Its becoming complicated to format them. Also, I cannot convert dict to a string and then do formatting.

```
  for item in [str(k) + " " + "".join(str(k1) + ": " + str(v1) + " " for k1, v1 in       v.items()) for k, v in d.items()]:
      print item
```

Comment: I don't see multi-line dictionaries, I see three separate one line dictionaries. How are you storing these dictionaries?

Comment: How are you reading the dictionaries from standard input? Are you doing `input` in Python 2? If so, try `raw_input`, which returns a string regardless of whether the input looks like a Python literal.

Comment: @Blckknght Check my code above. Thats how its done

Comment: @Marius dont want to store them

Answer (score 1):

Thefourtheye was faster, but here my version:

```
d = { 1 : {'1': 5, '2': 6, '3': 0},
      2 : {'1': 6, '2': 4, '3': 0},
      3 : {'1': 2, '2': 9, '3': 1} }

print('\n'.join('{} {}'.format(k, ' '.join('{}: {}'.format(k, v) for k, v in v.items())) for k, v in d.items()))
```

inb4: Why is the result not sorted? (standard dicts are never ordered.)

Comment: Can u see the code on top and tell me bec your solution does not work in my case.

Comment: You have various dictionaries and I merge them into one.

Comment: What is `d`? Where does it come from? What is its type and what is its content?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> data = { 1 : {'1': 5, '2': 6, '3': 0},
...  2 : {'1': 6, '2': 4, '3': 0},
...  3 : {'1': 2, '2': 9, '3': 1} }
>>> for k,v in data.items():
...     print k, " ".join("{}: {}".format(*i) for i in v.items())
... 
1 1: 5 3: 0 2: 6
2 1: 6 3: 0 2: 4
3 1: 2 3: 1 2: 9
```

Note that neither the order of the lines, or the order of the items on them is preserved, since `dict` is unordered

You can easily sort them like this

```
>>> for k,v in sorted(data.items()):
...     print k, " ".join("{}: {}".format(*i) for i in sorted(v.items()))
... 
1 1: 5 2: 6 3: 0
2 1: 6 2: 4 3: 0
3 1: 2 2: 9 3: 1
```

Comment: Can u see the code on top and tell me bec your solution does not work in my case